# Circular symmetry heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, mathematical-modeling, bessel-functions, heat-equation

We can model circularly symmetric diffusion in a circle with radius $a$ as a function of time and radial position by employing the  partial differential equation

$$
\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = \frac Dr \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial c}{\partial r}\right)
$$

where $c(r,t)$ is the concentration of particles with conditions $c(r,0)=c_0,c(a,t)=1, c(0,t) =$ finite. Solve to find the $c(r,t)$ in terms of bessel functions.

I used separation of variables and found the solution to be

$$
c(r,t)=\frac{J_0(\lambda r)}{J_0(\lambda a)} c_0 e^{-\lambda^2 D t}.
$$
I'm not sure if this is correct and I'm not sure how to find what $\lambda$ is. Any guidance would be great!

Comment: Your solution does not satisfy the conditions $c(r,0)=c_0$ and $c(a,t)=1$.

Comment: This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133670/circularly-symmetric-heat-equation?rq=1) may help you.

Comment: I see now that I should've used the superposition principle, but I'm confused on how I incorporate the specific boundary conditions for my problem and how I find the $\lambda$ value

Comment: If you work with $c = 1 + u$, you’ll need $u$ to vanish at $r=a$. That’ll lead you to zeros of the Bessel function.

Comment: Thank you so I've gone through it and $c(r,t) = 1 + \sum D_n J_0(\sqrt{\lambda_n} r) e^{-\lambda_n D t}$ with $D_n = \frac{\int_0^a (c_0-1)J_0(\sqrt{\lambda_n}r)r dr}{\int_0^a J_0^2 (\sqrt{\lambda_n}r) r dr}$. I tried to verify the initial and boundary conditions but I'm so confused when it comes to evaluating integrals with the bessel functions. I've never learned about bessel functions and I'm not sure of the different identities. Any insight would be appreciated.